# renaming a number of files by increasing their trailing number by a constant using bash script

Tags: bash, rename, filenames

I have these files in a directory:

```
mmm.1
mmm.2
mmm.3
.
.
.
.
.
```

i want to rename them as:

```
mmm.31
mmm.32
mmm.33
.
.
.
```

Just adding the number '30' to the trailing number in each file name.

Comment: Please do some research (our site has a search function, and there are many good search engines on the web) and try to solve this yourself.   Then [edit] your question to show what you tried and explain where you’re stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MODIFIED: After you informed us that you are dealing with ~300 files, the answers need to be modified. In the edited answer below, replace the number 300 with the exact upper-bound number for the pre-existing files.

```
for file in mmm.{300..1} ; do mv "${file}" "${file%.*}.$((30+${file#*.}))" ; done
```

This answer is very efficient because it does everything within `bash` using `bash` native abilities, and doesn't need external programs or launching of sub-processes.

1. `${file%.*}` returns the prefix of filename before the period.
2. `$((..)) is bash's math operation idiom.
3. `${file#*.}` returns the suffix of filename after the period. If you are concerned that you might have filenames with more than one embedded period, replace the `#` with `##`.

See `man bash` for further details and many other very cool native features.

Comment: @nikki: This answer now accounts for the overwrites.

Comment: Yes, it does. But there should be a dot after these: mv "${file}" "${file%.*}.

Comment: @9pp. quite right. corrected.